# Counting symbols qty without "!, ., , _"

Tags: python

```
def count_letters(let):
    count = 0
    for l in let:
        if l != ['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Here is my function that supposed to count amount of symbols except ['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']. When I running the program it is still counting all symbols. How I should modify my "if" statement in my code to run program correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `if l != ['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']` you are actually comparing `l` to the list. In other words, you are asking: If `l` is different to `['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']`, enter the `if` statement.

What you want to know is if `l` is not inside `['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']`. For that, you can use:

```
if l not in ['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']:
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 if l not in ['!',' ', '.', ',', '?']:
```

> x not in s returns the negation of x in s

Check the [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in)